# SUMO, Netconvert projection option --proj.plain-geo is missing. GEO coordinates not showing

Tags: sumo

I am running SUMO 0.30.0 on a ubuntu 16.04 OS in order to run simulations in Omnet++ (using Veins and/or Artery).

For some reason the SUMO GUI does not show any GEO coordinates in the bottom right corner. Also as is described in the title, the netconvert option `--proj.plan-geo` is missng.
The only projection options available are `--simple-projection` and `--proj.scale INT`.

I do have the proj libraries installed.
`$ proj
Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016
usage: proj [ -bCeEfiIlormsStTvVwW [args] ] [ +opts[=arg] ] [ files ]`

Can anybody help me find the source of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you did not install the proj development libraries but just proj before compiling. Try something like

```
sudo apt install libproj-dev
```

and then do `configure` and `make` again.

Comment: I tried it. The development libraries were not installed as you guessed. Sadly it didn't solve the problem. Still no geo-coordinates anywhere

Comment: The configure output has a summary at the end that mentions which features are enabled. Does it mention proj?

Comment: yes, it does. Even did so before the development libraries were installed.

Comment: Can you have a look at src/config.h whether HAVE_PROJ is defined?

Comment: Seems to be:   `/* defined if PROJ is available */ 
#define HAVE_PROJ 1`

Comment: Can you verify that the sumo you are running is the same that was build with this configuration? (What is the output of a simple `sumo` call without arguments?)

Comment: Now here's something interesting...  `SUMO Version 0.30.0
 Build features: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu TRACI GDAL GUI
 Copyright (C) 2001-2017 DLR and contributors; http://sumo.dlr.de
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL Version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html  >   Use --help to get the list of options.` Obviously I'm doing something wrong when rebuilding

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, but this time it worked just fine. Probably something stupid like forgot to invoke `make install` after `make`. Thanks very much for the help.